# What jquery Grid supports a continuous stream of updates (json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting, grid

**Since this is a huge post here is a short summary** (please read the hole post if you want to answer though):

Implemented now:

- Website pulls lot of json (full dataset everytime ~30kb, already gzipped)
- Renders data to as html table client side
- Too much traffic
- Too long rendering times

**Link to one of the sites: [Sample](http://www.bet-mate.com/Views/BetfairCoupon.aspx)**

We already implemented the partial data retrieval, what we need now is to find a solution that:

- Does only render the changes
- Flash updated cells

**Question: What grid or other solutions exist to make this happen?**

**UPDATE**: The client wants to see all available data at once, **no paging**.

---

Full description:

In our application we need to display a certain number of rows (~300-1000) in a grid. Visitors can **sort (client side)** by clicking on the headers. Additionally each row contains multiple links that open an **iframe using colorbox**.

The data

- is refreshed every 30 seconds (json from server)
- consists of multiple fields (strings, ints and decimals).
- Only the decimals are changing though, that means the links (colorbox) stay the same as well
- not all the data is displayed, some is used just for client side sorting

Currently we are using a combination of **jTemplates, tablesorter and colorbox** to render the entire json dataset into an html table. The current flow is:

1. Retreive data from server (full dataset)
2. Render data to html using jTemplates
3. Initialize colorbox for the table
4. Initialize tablesorter for the table
5. Start again from #1

The solution above works, but there are some issues:

- Lots of duplicate data gets
  transferred. This adds up fairly
  quickly (>5GB/day)
- The rendering of the data takes quite
  a while (~300ms), its worse on mobiles
- Reinitializing the colorbox and tablesorter every time take quite a while as well (~400ms), also worse on mobiles

So our goal is to **just transfer the updated and new data** via json. Every row has a simple unique key (int), so they can be identified easily.
Additionally we want to **flash** the container of the updated or newly inserted data, as a notification for the user that there have been changes.

The flow we have in mind is:

1. Get json data from server (**full set**)
2. Render grid with sorting and
   initialize colorbox links
3. Get json data from server (**only updated values and new rows**)
4. Update the grid (**only changed values and new rows**) <- also **flash** value containter after update
5. Start again from #3

So the grid we are looking for needs to support loading **data as a hole** and also loading **just the updated values**.

The full data set would look like:

```
{
    [ 
        { 
        "key":1, 
        "StaticProperty":"value3",
        "PropertyOne":2.85 ,
        "PropertyTwo":1.99
        },
        {
        "key":2, 
        "StaticProperty":"value2",
        "PropertyOne":5.66,
        "PropertyTwo":7.36
        },
        {
        "key":3, 
        "StaticProperty":"value3",
        "PropertyOne":1.78,
        "PropertyTwo":9.31
        },
        {
        "key":4, 
        "StaticProperty":"value4",
        "PropertyOne":1.78,
        "PropertyTwo":9.31
        },
        {
        "key":5, 
        "StaticProperty":"value5",
        "PropertyOne":1.78,
        "PropertyTwo":9.31
        }
    ]
};
```

The update data set would look like (remeber it will only contain the changed values):

```
{
    "updates" : [ 
        { 
        "key":1,
        "PropertyOne":4.88
        },
        {
        "key":2,
        "PropertyOne":2.77,
        "PropertyTwo":3.88
        },
        {
        "key":6,
        "StaticProperty":"value6",
        "PropertyOne":7.23,
        "PropertyTwo":8.42
        } 
    ],
    "deletes" : [ 4, 5 ]
};
```

As you can see the update can contain:

- partial updates (id #1)
- multiple updates per row (id #2)
- no updates for existing rows (id #3)
- ids of deleted rows as simple array (id #4, #5)
- new rows (id #6)

What we need is a grid or other suggestions that qould make us able to handle **all the mentioned operations**.
We already have a way to make sure that the data is never corrupted (already handled on server and client side), so its really *just* about **displaying the data and keeping the display up to date**.

All input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question:
**NO**, there is no such grid. We will have to build it from scratch.
I will update this question/answer with the url to the completed grid as soon as it's in place though to give others a head start.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought... your already using jquery and json... have you considered ajax? since your doing only updates, you would be able to locate the id in the table for the updates using the json from the jquery and update only those rows.

this would help your rendering and traffic by a huge ammount.  set the jquery to run the ajax on a timer with a set background object that pulls only the updated rows.

Personally I like repeaters, but that is a personally preference... you could set the on page load to load a cached version of the data set, then allow the jquery to take over and pull back data async.

Comment: Thx for the tip. This actually already happens, we are using the ajax function of jquery, the issue is to more updating the values in the ui and the speed of rendering. i would rather use an existing component than do that on foot ;)

Comment: i have part of an application that i work on that renders a repearter in full, and then i go back (click function) and have to update specific sections from a web service source... it takes forever if i try to do it all at once, thats why i brought up ajax... i love the stuff.

Comment: Hi, sry for the late response, as I said before we are already using ajax requests to pull the data from the server. What we want to avoid is manually updating the values in the DOM. Apparently it seems there is no such component however :(

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite jQuery based Grid plugin is the [jQuery flexigrid plugin](http://www.flexigrid.info/).

It's pretty feature rich. You can specify whether to load the table records on page load or specify a nice function which returns XML / JSON which will then automatically be output. I've personally used it plenty of times with ASP .Net applications to call supporting webservices and then render the results each time.

Based on your request, the main thing it doesn't have is a refresh timer but you can simply start a timer yourself and then call the data refresh method of the grid which will fire off a new JSON request each time.

Comment: To my knowledge it does not support just updating based on changes, but it needs the entire dataset to be initialized(only the first json request will return the entire data set, afterwards just changes). Did I miss something?

Comment: Surely throwing down the entire dataset is always going to be pretty expensive in the first place? Why not just let flexigrid startup on the page load and then request the current "page" worth of data via a quick ajax / json request. This will be pretty inexpensive as you are only showing the results for your current view subset each time.

Comment: You are right, but this is not wanted by the client. The entire idea of the website is to give an overview of all available data without paging, I should update the question to reflect that though.

Comment: What about serving the XML up to the client side during the server request, hide it inside a hidden element. Then on load, init the flexigrid using the entire XML set. Any changes afterwards, update the XML using jQuery XML functions and reset the flexigrid with the latest version of your XML?

Comment: Sry for getting back so late. Xml is way to much overhead, we already server 20GB/day by using gzipped json, one reason to only transfer changes is to minimize the traffic. What your suggesting is pretty much manually updating the data in the dom once the flexgrid has been populated. First this is a lot of manual coding (which we wanted to avoid) and second I don't know what will happen to the soring if I just update the data, probably it will still contain the old values and therefore not work properly anymore.